# Storing images binaries inside a triple-store vs. storing only a url reference

Tags: image, triplestore

I have many milions of entity resources stored in a triple store where a (sparql) query may return many hundreds (or thousands) of them (the result will be further nerrowed with e.g., pivot viewer where thumbnail images of the entities should be displayed).

Now, most answers on this subject suggests storing the images outside the triple-store having a uri reference inside the triple store (e.g., foaf:Image) pointing to the resource image.

If I store them inside the triple-store I suppose I'll get a better performance with one sparql query to the backend store (fetching the entities and their thumbnail images).

On the other hand, with images stored outside the triple-store I'll have to do many queries to fetch the images.

What would be the best practice for handling such a case ? (may apply to other binary data properties of an entity resource).

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet in this case is to store the images separately.  Most triple-stores do not have optimized blob storage and you might degrade the performance of all queries by including the binary data in the database.

You'd still be able to get all the images for some request in a single query -- probably, depends on the request I guess, but it *is* possible.  What I'd suggest is that your URL references to the images are served by something like Apache.  That way you can feed clients the URLs directly and they can fetch them in whatever manner is best; think of this like a browser getting a webpage which uses images, the images aren't part of the HTML, it gets them separately.

You can handle uploads of images, if need be, by splitting the request and putting your image metadata in your triplestore while putting the actual bits of the images in your Apache hosted directory.

This also lets you set up caching and other standard HTTP level infrastructure for serving the images as quickly and as easily as possible, which I think will end up giving you the best level of performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this still hold when we talk about say couple of thousands of images?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?  Apache is a pretty good web server and can handle serving thousands of images.  Any triple store on the market can handle a few thousand triples storing the URLs of the images.